# Removed network-manager and now stuck

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and in a step by step to install clonezilla I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager
```

The next step was to modify the interfaces file (which I did as below) but it didn't work.

Now my usb wireless card isn't recognized and I can't find a way to get network-manager back. I tried going into

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

and modified it :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
address (my local ip)
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

I still can't connect any more after rebooting and trying a

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

If I type in:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

I can see that it sees the card (I'm trying to run my usb wireless) but it shows:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description : network controller ... etc 

*-network DISABLED 
description : Wireless interface... etc.
```

EDIT:

```
No DHCPOFFERS received
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping
run-parts --verbose in persistent database - sleeping
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvxonf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoips
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-deamon
"" "" /ethool
"" "" /ntpdate
"" ""/upstart
"" ""/wpasupplicant
```

---

reboot results:

[image]

Comment: try `ifup -a` or `ifup eth0`

Comment: Doesnt work. Do i need the info in the interfaces file with that?? or simply runing that command should do the trick

Comment: in you /etc/network/interfaces file, does the second line begin with `face` or with `iface`?

Comment: iface sorry typo.

Comment: K - Your specifying `dhcp` but using static addressing, perhaps that line should be `iface eth0 inet static`

Comment: thats what I had at first u can change it back. btw everytime i make a change to that file how can i validate if it works? reboot or runing ifup -a or another command?

Comment: I'm not sure - we're a little over my head - I do know you need to re0run the `/etc/init.d/networking restart` after modifying the interfaces file.

Comment: Do you have the `lo` interface defined? http://www.geekyprojects.com/cloning/setup-a-clonezilla-server-on-ubuntu/

Comment: This is what i have there :auto lo iface lo inet loopback

Comment: K - we've exhausted what I can think of.

Comment: Are you sure it's `eth0` and not `eth1` or `eth2`?

Comment: @CharlesGreen 100% sure

Comment: Please correct the typo in the question.

Comment: @Aders done. sorry totally forgot

Comment: A small files like `/e/n/interfaces` should be copied exactly.  You stop interfaces that have stanza in `interfaces` with `ifdown eth0` and start with `ifup eth0`. Remember to **stop** interface before editing `interfaces`.  No need to restart any service for testing.  Are you shore about the name?  For wireless, try `sudo iwlist scan` to see if someone responces.  Have you looked into `/var/log/messages`, `/v/l/syslog` and `/v/l/dmesg` for any reported missing firmware?

Comment: @Anders I haven't done any of those. I'm totally new to linux. I will try that in a moment thanks a lot.

Comment: You have a USB wireless interface.  Try `tail -f /var/log/syslog /var/log/messages` (might need `sudo(8)` if you are not in the right group, the `adm` group in this case, as `ls -l /var/log/dmesg` shows.  `sudo addgroup _yourlogin_ adm` will fix this for next login)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18576/discussion-between-anders-and-phadaphunk).

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm that your ethernet card has a driver and has created an interface, ideally eth0:

```
ifconfig
```

If so, please amend your /etc/network/interfaces file to read:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now try to connect:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

The '-v' for verbose should produce some output telling us either that you connected or what went wrong. If so, we'll try to correct it.

Please try a reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

Comment: I'll update my post with the results

Comment: Please see my edit in a few moments.

Comment: you want the result of the reeboot or the results of the ifdown command after the reeboot

Comment: performed a reboot same results after the reboot.

Comment: added reboot results to the initial question

Comment: did you get a chance to look at the reboot results? :S